# How to override whole json document in mongodb update call

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I must admit I am not exactly sure what is going on inside of the mongodbclient function update. In my code I currently have this:

```
app.post('/update', function(req, res) {
  const params = req.body;

  const newData = {
    id: params.id,
    data: params.data
    a ton more fields will go here
  };

  db.collection('datas').update({id : params.id}, 
      { $set: {data : newData.data}}, (err, data) => {
            if (!err) {
              res.send({err: false});
            } else {
              res.send({err: true});
            }
 });
```

However I dont have the slightest idea what the whole $set bracket is doing or how I could modify it to override the entire document once there are a ton more fields on the incoming data. I suppose the id field really wont need to be updated but you can get the idea.

What is that bracket doing? And how can I customize it for my needs?

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to override the entire document you can remove the $set tag.

$set simply sets the fields that you pass into it.
If you do not pass a $set or $unset command it will assume you are trying to overwrite the entire document.

Take the following document for example

```
{
    _id: 1,
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
}
```

Using set such as:

```
db.collection.update(
    {_id: 1},
    {$set: {
        a:2,
        b:4,
        new: 123
    }}
);
```

would return the following:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    a: 2,
    b: 4,
    c: 3,
    new: 123
}
```

It updates a and b that were passed in but does not alter c as it was not passed in

using $unset will remove a field

```
db.collection.update(
    {_id: 1},
    {$unset: {
        new: true
    }}
);
```

would then return:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    a: 2
    b: 4,
    c: 3
}
```

Without passing in $set or $unset you can alter an entire document

```
db.collection.update(
    {_id: 1},
    {
        comment: "what have I done to my data?!?!?!"
    }
);
```

This will return, keeping _id unchanged but overwriting the entire document in the process

```
{
    _id: 1,
    comment: "what have I done to my data?!?!?!"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$set expects an hash. newData is already an hash, and it's the hash you need, so try:

```
$set: newData
```

Instead of

```
$set: {data: newData.data}
```

It should work.

Comment: What is the meaning of hash in this scenario?

Comment: Sorry, I guess the correct name of an hash in Javascript is Associative Array. This is an hash: hash = { id: 1, name: 'John'}. This is an array: array = ['blue', 'yellow']

Comment: This does not override the entire document unless the entire new document is passed in each time.
If you just want to update a single field which is usually the case the $set (or $unset) operator is required but to replace an object then it can be prohibitive